# What is the scope of "Crawl this Url and Direct Links" in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, fetch-as-google

In Google Webmaster Tools you can use the "Fetch as Google" feature to have Google download a page from your site.   Once you have done so, you can click the "Submit to Index" button which gives you the following options:

[image]

If you select "Crawl this Url and Direct Links" does it only crawl links that are part of your domain or all links (even external links)?

Google's documentation for this feature is [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en) and it does not address this question.  It only says:

> Select Crawl this URL and its direct links to submit the URL as well as all the other pages that URL links to for re-crawling. You can submit up to 10 of requests of this kind per month.

It doesn't say whether or not it will re-crawl URLs linked from the page to other domains.

Comment: Only the links associated with your site.

Comment: I assume it doesnt traverse over subdomains ?

Comment: Sub-domains? Probably does not crawl them.

Answer (score -1):

IIRC, there is an option that lets you choose whether you want to crawl only the specified URL or all the URL in that domain.

Comment: That's the question; what does that do? How does it work?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about "in that domain" that I can find.     The documentation says "all the other pages that URL links to".